# Count no of lines between two lines

Tags: java

How to achieve the following. Here is a sample text file..

```
AH
1
2
3
BH
21
BT03
CH
CT02
AT10
```

This is a sample text file. I need read each line and find the count.. For example, there are 10 Lines within A record.. And 3 lines within B record and two lines within C Record.

How do I get this count. H-Header and T-Trailer.  You may say,  read the T record to find the count, but that count might be wrong.  Hence I am trying to find the count and update the trailer records correctly.

I cannot upload the Java code I have written as I'm on mobile now.. Any suggestions is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be to post your question when you're actually able to post your question.  You won't get a good answer by posting only half your question.

Comment: Why this is being down voted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, you just want to count lines in a file? Try something like this:

```java
Path path = Paths.get("yourFile.txt");
long lineCount = Files.lines(path).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code and read all file in array.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[10];

    int length = stringArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String stringI = stringArray[i];
        if (stringI.contains("H")) {
            // Head rec
            String headRecName = stringI.replace("H", "");
            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                count++;
                String stringJ = stringArray[j];
                if (stringJ.contains("T") && headRecName.equals(stringJ.replace("T", ""))) {
                    stringArray[j] = stringArray[j] + count;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```